# multiple templates angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

supose these divs inside a component:

```
<div ngIf="condition1">   
<button (click)="set_condition1_false_and_2_true()">show-template-2</button> 
</div>

<div ngIf="condition2>   
<button (click)="set_condition2_false_and_3_true()">show-template-3</a> 
</div>

<div ngIf="condition3>   
<a>Last Template</a>
</div>
```

assuming the typescript is working right with the booleans, what i need to do to make this view?

(observation)
with two divs i make it works:

```
<div *ngIf="condition1; else secondTemplate>
  <button (click)="make_condition1_false_and_2_true()">showSecondTemplate
</button>
</div>

<ng-template #secondTemplate>
  <a>Second Template Works</a>
</ng-templante>
```

but i need three templates in the same component

Comment: You might want to break your "different templates" into separate components and render these child components in a parent component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest, but probably not the best, way would be to simply check the other conditions are not true in your *ngIf statements.

Omitting all the code other than the ifs

```
<div *ngIf="!condition2 && !condition3 && condition1">   

<div *ngIf="!condition1 && !condition3 && condition2">   

<div *ngIf="!condition1 && !condition2 && condition3>
```

Alternatively you could use [NgSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch). This is easy if all your conditions are based on the same variable, but assuming they are not you can do it using a helper function.

```
<div [ngSwitch]="getState()">
  <div *ngSwichCase="1">   
  <div *ngSwichCase="2">   
  <div *ngSwichCase="3"> 
</div>
```

Then in your typescript define the getState function using if/then/else

```
getState() {
  if (condition1) {
    return 1;
  } else if (condition2) {
    return 2;
  } else {
    return 3;
  }
}
```

In your real code you would want to use a more meaningful name and also return an Enumeration value with a meaningful name rather than magic numbers.

Comment: ok. but considering that the first way you did won't work because the the next divs won't render (the divs with ngIf was my first attempt. it doesn't work), you are sure that ngswitch support render next divs based on conditions changed by buttons? because, you know, this is the problem to deal with <ng-template>

Comment: I am no longer sure what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want exactly one of the three blocks to be displayed at any times or are multiple of them supposed to be displayed? Your first example would work if you want to allow more than one to be displayed at a time (if you fixed the unclosed tags).

Comment: yeah, maybe there's something wrong with my angular. the ng switch is adding the second div to the template when the button is clicked, but the first isn't disappearing. with the ngIf was happening the opposite. the first was removed but the second wasn't rendering. the only way it worked was with ng-template and ngif/else. but only with two templates.

Comment: now works. the problem was, i had some problems with the service on ts. thanks.